# Oracle SQL query for finding paycheck where count = 1 or does not exist where count > 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table name Paychecks. Within the table I have Employee_ID, Employee_Record and Paycheck_nbr. My table has bad data in the sense that a paycheck_nbr should be unique for every Employee_Id. I need to filter out that bad data and get only one unique Paycheck_nbr to an Employee_ID.

Example of Bad Data

| Employee_ID | Employee_Record | Paycheck_Nbr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 3 | 99 |
| 456 | 2 | 99 |
| 789 | 2 | 99 |

Example of Good Data

| Employee_ID | Employee_Record | Paycheck_Nbr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 97 |
| 456 | 2 | 98 |
| 789 | 3 | 99 |

Comment: Considering `Employee_ID=789`, how can I say that (789, 2, 99) is bad data and (789, 3, 99) is good data and not viceversa? What's the criteria? Could you share a full table and point out for each row, which is good and which is bad (and why if necessary)?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. **Show us the actual code that you've tried**, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely sure, but it looks to me like an attempt to get the employee data (that are bad/confusing/non-distinctive) - reorganized. If it is an attempt to make the data more distinctive and in some kind of order than you could try to deal with it like below:

```sql
--  First the sample data (this is not the part of answer - just some data to work with)
WITH
    a_table AS
        (
            Select '123' "EMPLOYEE_ID", 3 "EMPLOYEE_RECORD", 99 "PAYCHECK_NBR" From DUAL Union All
            Select '456' "EMPLOYEE_ID", 2 "EMPLOYEE_RECORD", 99 "PAYCHECK_NBR" From DUAL Union All
            Select '789' "EMPLOYEE_ID", 2 "EMPLOYEE_RECORD", 99 "PAYCHECK_NBR" From DUAL 
        )
--  --------   the answer   -----------------
Select
    EMPLOYEE_ID "EMPLOYEE_ID",
    --
    -- reindexing EMPLOYEE_RECORD - generate indexes ordered by EMPLOYEE_ID
    Count(1) OVER(ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "EMPLOYEE_RECORD",
    --
    -- calculate PAYCHECK NUMBER - preserve max PAYCHECK_NMBR and calculate the rest of them ordered by new indexes
    Max(PAYCHECK_NBR) OVER() -      Count(EMPLOYEE_ID) OVER() +     Count(1) OVER(ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "PAYCHECK_NBR"
    -- max is 99 ------             ---- number of employees = 3    --- new indexes are [1, 2, 3]  ---------
From
    a_table
Order By 
    EMPLOYEE_ID
```

And here is the result:

| EMPLOYEE_ID | EMPLOYEE_RECORD | PAYCHECK_NBR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 97 |
| 456 | 2 | 98 |
| 789 | 3 | 99 |

I used analytic functions to do the job. More about them here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

... if we add some more sample rows and make changes to EMPLOYEE_RECORD and PAYCHECK_NBR columns mixing the data like this:

```sql
WITH
    a_table AS
        (
            Select '123' "EMPLOYEE_ID", 3 "EMPLOYEE_RECORD", 90 "PAYCHECK_NBR" From DUAL Union All
            Select '456' "EMPLOYEE_ID", 2 "EMPLOYEE_RECORD", 97 "PAYCHECK_NBR" From DUAL Union All
            Select '789' "EMPLOYEE_ID", 3 "EMPLOYEE_RECORD", 97 "PAYCHECK_NBR" From DUAL Union All
            Select '890' "EMPLOYEE_ID", 4 "EMPLOYEE_RECORD", 99 "PAYCHECK_NBR" From DUAL Union All
            Select '903' "EMPLOYEE_ID", 4 "EMPLOYEE_RECORD", 96 "PAYCHECK_NBR" From DUAL Union All
            Select '956' "EMPLOYEE_ID", 6 "EMPLOYEE_RECORD", 99 "PAYCHECK_NBR" From DUAL 
        )
```

... than the resulting dataset would still be reorganized in the same manner...

| EMPLOYEE_ID | EMPLOYEE_RECORD | PAYCHECK_NBR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 94 |
| 456 | 2 | 95 |
| 789 | 3 | 96 |
| 890 | 4 | 97 |
| 903 | 5 | 98 |
| 956 | 6 | 99 |

Regards...